# How to grab multiple lines after matching a line in Perl?

Tags: perl

My file looks like this:

```
1  15
2  16
3  18
4  19
5  25
6  30
7  55
8  45
9  34
10 52
```

If the matched pattern is 30 in line 6, I would like to grab N lines before and M lines after the line 6, for example if N=3 and M=4 so the result is expected to be like this:

```
3  18
4  19
5  25
6  30
7  55
8  45
9  34
10 52
```

I am a very new beginner in Perl and any advice would be appreciated.

﹟UPDATE
Many thanks for these helpful advice below and I really appreciate them.
Here is my updated code for this and any suggestions are welcome!

```
my $num;

while(<>)
{   
if ( /pattern/) 
{$num = $. ;}   
}

open (,"") || die ("Can't open the file");

while(<>)

{
if (  $. >= $num-N and $. <=$num+M)
{    
print OUT "$_ \r";
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to find two matches within 4 lines of each other? If so, then what?

Comment: Unless you're doing this as a learning exercise, you might consider ack or grep: `ack ' 30' --before-context 3 --after-context 4 DATA_FILE`.

Comment: @FMc Many thanks for your advice about ack and grep and really appreciate that. This is only my learning exercise on perl.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an array (I'll call it `@preceding`) of the last `N` lines read. When the pattern is matched, stop updating this array and start inserting lines into another array (`@following`). Do this until `@following` has `M` lines in it.

It should look something like this (fixed now thanks to ikegami):

```
my $matched = 0;
my @preceding;
my @following;
while(<>){
    if ($matched){
        push ( @following, $_);
        last if @following == M;
        next;
    }
    else {
        push ( @preceding, $_);
        shift(@preceding) if @preceding > N;
    }
    $matched = 1 if /pattern/;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. However, I still failed to print the data I need using these codes above...:( I will try it later

Comment: @Sam If you need to print it, just print the contents of preceding and following.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @lines = <>;
foreach $idx (grep { $lines[$_] =~ /pattern/ } 0..$#lines) {
    print join (map {$lines[$_]} grep { $_ >= $idx - $B && $_ <= $idx +$A } 0..$#lines)."\n";
}
```

You can also use the GNU grep command, with -A,-B flags for that exact purpose.

```
  -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups of
          matches.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before matching lines.
          Places a  line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups  of
          matches.
```

Comment: Many thanks for this which gives me a constructive and helpful idea! Really appreciate!